# Problem with this code and I can't understand the lambda function

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a question about this code in python.

```
xs = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}

xm = sorted(xs.items(), key = lambda x : x[1])

print(xm)
```

I understand the sorted and items but that lambda I don't know how it works and why it works.

I need to order the dictionary from the value not from the keys.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: does this solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is pretty simple.

Sorted tries to sort the collection based on some criteria.

1. If it is a list strings, it does the string comparison wherein `a comes before b` and `aa comes before ab`.
2. For list of int, `1 comes before 2` and so on.

In your case, you are passing, a dictionary. So, Python will try to sort them based on their `keys` value which is a string in this case. `REMEMBER, when you do dict.items(), you get a list of tuples and item at 0th index is the key`

So the below code will give the following result.

```
xs = {'a': 4, 'x': 3, 'z': 2, 'd': 1}
xm = sorted(xs.items())
print(xm)
```

**OUTPUT** -

```
[('a', 4), ('d', 1), ('x', 3), ('z', 2)]
```

Here you see that, a comes before d and d comes before x and z.

Now what if we don't want to use the default behaviour. Instead of using the `key` as the sorting criteria, we could use the `value`. In order for that to achieve, we need to tell the sorted function that fetch the `values` from tuples and then use them for comparision.

Following code does the same. lambda will receive the tuple as `x` and return `x[1]` which is the value in dictionary.

```
xs = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}

xm = sorted(xs.items(), key = lambda x : x[1])

print(xm)
```

**OUTPUT**

[('d', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 4)]

Here, 1 comes before 2 and 3 and 4.

Now, if you update the lambda as `lambda x : x[0]`, you are explicitly tell the sorted function to use the dict key as sorting criteria which is a default behavior

[('d', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 4)]

```
xs = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}

xm = sorted(xs.items(), key = lambda x : x[0])

print(xm)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)] # same as before without the lambda
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i think i get it!

Answer (score 1):

*Why it works?* So, you're using `sorted` function that accepts a function as second parameter. This parameter, in your case, is used for sorting by values, not by keys. Why?

`xs.items()` returns `dict_items([('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)])` an object with array of tuples.
When you use `sorted(xs)`, sorted function looks inside the array and considers the first element of the tuple, in your case 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'. It makes a sort looking this value, 'cause 'a' is less than 'b' and etc.

Let's consider another example, using `xs` with elements not sorted by key by default:

```
xs = {'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'a': 4, 'd': 1}
```

This one has `xs.items()` =

```
dict_items([('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('a', 4), ('d', 1)]
```

But, when you use `sorted` func you got:

```
>>> xm = sorted(xs.items())
>>> xm
[('a', 4), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)]
```

You sorted by the first element of the tuple.

So, this is the same of write:

```
xm = sorted(xs.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Alias = *I wanna order the array `xs.items()` by its first element, also called `key`*

But `xs.items()` also returns the value as second element of the tuple, so, if you write something like this (same of your code):

```
xm = sorted(xs.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

you're saying: *I wanna order the array `xs.items()` by its second element, also called `value`*.
The value of `xs` are: `[3, 2, 4, 1]` (in your case [4, 3, 2, 1]).
So, it orders element following the rule of "less than". At the end of your code, you will see an array with, takes the tuple at place `i`, its second element, will be *less than* second element of the tuple `i+1`.

---

If you want the inverse, so, ordered by *greater than*, you could use the param `reverse=True`

Comment: I think i get it...i hope...thanks a lot!

Comment: @DanielTanc upvote from my side since your explanation is really good.

Comment: @gsb22 thanks for the upvote. I posted this comment a couple of seconds before yours. Your explanation is also good, in fact the same, more or less. My upvote is yours ;)